# What kind of adhesive is this and what will remove it easily?

Tags: flooring

I've been ripping all of the carpet out of our home. Everything was going great until I got to these stairs with this yellow-y stuff. It's very strange to me that it's only on this section of stairs and wasn't anywhere else in house where carpet was removed.

The home was built in the early 1900s. Not sure when the carpet was added, but it's ooollllddddd.

It's really odd to me that someone would put this much adhesive under carpet in addition to staples. It also has that tire tread pattern. Maybe before there was carpet, someone decided they needed something to prevent slips?

Can anyone tell me what it is? I'm wondering out of general curiosity and also because going after it with a putty knife is slow going.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like any sort of adhesive to me.

It looks like underlay - long dead, crusty & now solidly adhered to the wood beneath it. This was a process of time, not glue.
It will, at some point in its early life, have been rubbery & springy,. to improve the walk feel of the carpet above it & also give the carpet a slightly longer life-span.

It is now what that possibly rubber has become after being down long enough to have just about petrified.

I'm not sure there's any better way to get it up than scraping.

It should go without saying that you want to be wearing a high-grade dust mask.

It should be noted that, of the two ways this stuff goes after 50 years or so, you got the tough one. The cheap stuff just turns to dust & can be hoovered up with little trouble.

A quick google turned up that some fitters **did** use glue to stick underlay [I've never seen one glued in any property I've ever lived in, all old Victorian houses, but that's still a small sample set]

Recommendations seem to generally be 'latex remover, the same as you'd use for latex paint'… followed by a lot more scraping, I'm afraid.
One recommended a heat gun - a balance between softening the glue & setting light to the underlay. I'd go carefully on that one.

Comment: I should have noted that only half the stairs had this, and I removed carpet along with underlay. What you're saying makes a lot of sense though I've been in smothering it with some citristrip which is helping quite a bit and gives me a little comfort (in case there is as asbestos) since it scrapes off very wet.

Answer (score 1):

If a hand scraper requires too much elbow grease, you can always use a SDS-plus scraper. It's very effective at removing stubborn tiles and thinset, it'll probably work on your stuff if it's brittle.

[image]

If it's not hard and brittle, I mean if it has kept its original rubbery texture, you can always use the scraper blade on an oscillating multitool.

Wear ear and eye protection, and a good mask.

Comment: Use caution with power scraping (either of the recommended tools). It'll be easy to gouge into the wooden stair treads which will then require repair work on them. If they'll be recovered in carpet, the repair can be quick and ugly, but if the goal is to leave exposed wooden treads, then keeping repair work to a minimum is important.

Comment: Yes it has to be used along the grain, not perpendicular, or it'll split the wood